# React Unexpected Token with Async

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I am trying to define a function as you see below.

```
const fetchRoles = async () => {
      const fetchedRoles = await axiosInstance.get('/roles/');
      setRoles(fetchedRoles.data)
}
```

And I am getting error "Unexpected token () ^=>".
Why I am getting this error ?
I am using node version v12.18.2 and npm version 6.14.7

Thanks..

Comment: This function looks okay. Can you share the entire component.

Comment: hi @Hyetigran, For example this is a function. And exported default. So not component.

Comment: Based on the snippet you provided the only suggestion would be to call your axios instances i.e. `const fetchedRoles = await axiosInstance().get('/roles/');`

Comment: Hi @Hyetigran, I found the problem. This error comes from eslint-loader. I updated ecmaVersionn 8 and problem is solved. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
For their person who may experience this problem,
This error comes from eslint-loader. So I updated eslint config with ecmaVersio 8 and problem solved.

My parser conf,

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    }
  }
```